# Map XML using attributes as value with dynamic nodes

Tags: xml, go

I am attempting to convert data stored in xml documents into an alternative data store. I have tried a variety of techniques but none have proven effective. The problem is the xml does not have a fixed schema and has an unconventional structure. A sample of the xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
    <f.1 value="field value" />
    <f.2 value="other value" />
    <f.3 value="field value 2" />
    <withchildren>
        <f.3.1 value="testvalue" />
        <f.3.2 value="test value 3" />
    </withchildren>
</Data>
```

Ideally the end result should store the result in `map[string]interface{}` in order to convert the value into a standard multi-dimensional JSON format.

Comment: You need to decide what that "schema" is going to be regardless, otherwise there's no way to know what elements/attributes map to what data structures. What is the structure you want to create?

Comment: @JimB The target data store is an elastic search store. The unknown elements are based on a variety of factors manually driven by legacy requirements. There is a schema-based header record, but there are a variety of elements that would be impossible to map to a schema as they are essentially an array of responses.

Comment: I put schema in quotes, because I didn't mean a literal XML schema, I meant a programatic "schema" for how you intend to translate the XML to something with a different structure that isn't XML. XML can't map directly to json, so you need some definition of how you intend to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're unsure about the structure [goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) is probably your best bet. Your tag names look a little odd I assume that's just for the sample. The code below uses the tag name for the key and uses the value attribute but you can modify it for any structure.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    xml := `
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <Data>
          <f1 value="field value"></f1>
          <f2 value="other value"></f2>
          <f3 value="field value 2"></f3>
          <withchildren>
              <f31 value="testvalue"></f31>
              <f32 value="test value 3"></f32>
          </withchildren>
      </Data>
      `
    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    reader := strings.NewReader(xml)

    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(reader)
    children := doc.Find("Data").Children()

    children.Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

        val, exists := s.Attr("value")
        if exists {
            data[goquery.NodeName(s)] = val
        }

        withchildren := s.Children()

        if withchildren.Length() > 0 {
            withchildren.Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
                val, exists := s.Attr("value")
                if exists {
                    data[goquery.NodeName(s)] = val
                }

            })
        }
    })
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

And if you really have no idea what the structure could be or how many nested elements there might be try this recursive version.

If you have multiple elements with the same name then you could modify the code to add a number with the key name. So "tag1", "tag2", etc.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    xml := `
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <Data>
          <f1 value="field value"></f1>
          <f2 value="other value"></f2>
          <f3 value="field value 2"></f3>
          <withchildren>
              <f31 value="testvalue"></f31>
              <f32 value="test value 3"></f32>
          </withchildren>
      </Data>
      `
    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    reader := strings.NewReader(xml)

    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(reader)
    children := doc.Find("Data").Children()
    data = getElements(children)
}

func getElements(children *goquery.Selection) map[string]interface{} {
    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    children.Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        val, exists := s.Attr("value")
        if exists {
            data[goquery.NodeName(s)] = val
        }

        if s.Children().Length() > 0 {
            data[goquery.NodeName(s)] = getElements(s.Children())
        }
    })
    return data
}
```

There are also some Go packages that I haven't used.

[mxj](https://github.com/clbanning/mxj) converts xml to map[string]interface{}

[goxml2json](https://github.com/basgys/goxml2json) converts from xml to json.